# <compatible-screens> excludes app from Nexus 5x in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

The app I am developing now is not visible in Google Play from Nexus 5x. 
As it does not support tablets, there is a `<compatible-screens>` section in the manifest (as suggested in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps)):

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
   <!-- XXHdpi Screen -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- XXXHdpi Screen -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

But I can't use `<supports-screens>` because of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps) (I need to completely filter out the app from tablets):

> Caution: If you use the `<supports-screens>` element for the reverse scenario (when your application is not compatible with larger screens) and set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external services such as Google Play do not apply filtering. Your application will still be available to larger screens, but when it runs, it will not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp; see Screen Compatibility Mode for more information). If you want to prevent your application from being downloaded on larger screens, use `<compatible-screens>`, as discussed in the previous section about Declaring an App is Only for Handsets.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem **except adding line with 420 density to `<compatible-screens>`**?

Comment: Why can't you use the line with 420 in `<compatible-screens>`?

Comment: Because it's not a solution, it's a hack. It'll work but when the next device with some other density in x-xxhdpi range arrives I'll have to add that device's density too.

Comment: Unfortunately Google hasn't been very helpful in regards to this issue. So another possible solution is to add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />` and manually exclude the small number of tablets with sim cards.

Comment: @MargaritaLitkevych, Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm experiencing the exact same problem - We need to exclude all tablets, and just adding 420 now is a hack that will break sooner or later for another device.

Comment: @bartzy, unfortunately, I didn't find any non-hack solution. As [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) says, we should not even use <compatible-screens> anymore, so this is a limitation :(

Answer (score 13):

According to [Google](https://design.google.com/devices/) the Nexus 5X has a xxhdpi screen but with a density of 2,6.
So 2,6 * 160 (mdpi) = 416, but according to [Android developers' site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) the accepted value is 420.
So just add
    `<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />`

UPDATE: The new 5" Google Pixel has the same density so the same rule applies for it as well.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not a solution I'm looking for. Yes, for Nexus 5x this line will work, but what if some other device arrives with other density in x-xxhdpi range? I'm looking for more general way to fix this issue.

Comment: In that case I suggest changing the question or simply asking another question.