# How supporting screens with non-standart DPI

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have an application without tablet support using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/41224771/7609373, but this implementation does not support devices with non-standard DPI, such as 408, which are found on Huawei devices. But google play is against using 408 and 410 in the manifest. How can such devices be supported?

Comment: FYI (new) huawei devices can't use the play store anymore https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/bqmnyg/google_pulls_huaweis_android_license/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Well, the old ones support it, and they have a good market share. And I guess this is not only sick of Huawei.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to understand the scaling factor in android,
Below link will be useful for you 
[Android doc Link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#java)

Let say in your case, you want to support dpi range between 320+ to 480 dpi. Your support for device falls into the following range

```
xlarge XHDPI and normal XXHDPI resolution
```

I will prefer the following way..

```
1) For every imageview, I will have fixed width and height in dp values
   ex: width=60dp && height = 60dp.

2) LayoutContainer width and height ideally you need to use match_parent and  wrap_content.

3) I will place drawable in XHDPI and XXHDPI only.
   drawable-xhdpi
   drawable-xxhdpi

4) I will create and place layouts in 
     layout-xhdpi-xlarge-port
     layout-xxhdpi-port

5) Try to use dimens.xml where dimensions such as dp and sp can be different for different resolution
     values-xhdpi-xlarge
     values-xxhdpi

6) Include screen resolution in manifest, which you need to support

   <compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                .
                                .
                                .
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
                                .
                                .
                                .
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

<!--- Adding support for Huwaei devices -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="320" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
                           or
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
</manifest>

7) Do the last thing now in manifest file again....
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"/>

Above are some of these ways you can support non-standard dpi devices...
```

Comment: The idea is good, but it does not solve the problem. I need to exclude large and xLarge screens size (table devices). And at the same time support non-standard displays

Comment: You do not believe me, okay, I did as you wrote to me, that's what I received when adding to GooglePlay: An invalid <compatible-screens> line was found in the AndroidManifest.xml file: 500/408

Comment: Try this.. <!--- Adding support for Huwaei devices -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="320" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />

Comment: <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />

Comment: Most likely this does not help, at the moment I can not verify such an implementation. But the fact that it will add support for tablet PCs is a fact.

Comment: <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"/>  it not works.

Comment: if you want try with android:largeScreens="true" and android:xlargeScreens="false"