# Devices with screen density 440 dpi are not compatible with app being published on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console

After adding `<compatible-screens>` block to AndroidManifest.xml some devices become incompatible. For example Pixel 3 and Pixel 3a. Both have a density screen 440 DPI. However all other devices from Google are compatible. The thing is I need to support limited set of devices (the UI is not suitable for tablets or devices with low resolutions).

My idea was these devices might belong to

```xml
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

or

```xml
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

buckets.

Setting `android:screenDensity="440"` is not working. Google Play prohibits uploading apk with such screen density.

Here is a mentioned above complete block of code

```xml
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

I was trying to upload apk files with different combinations of  `screenSize` and `screenDensity` and check if those devices become compatible. I have not found it yet.

Comment: @leven have you got any solution for this.

Comment: @Rameshbabu Not yet. I decided not to use the `compatible-screens` tag at all. At this moment if you use `compatible-screens` tag (it doesn't matter what the `screenSize` and `screenDensity` are - I tried all combinations of it), Pixel 3 and Pixel 3a will not be available for your app.

Comment: it's 2021 now and we still can't specify screenDensity 440... now there's pixel 3, 3a, 4, 4a and 5! And there's no workaround if we use compatible-screens tag :(

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in `AndroidManifest.xml` above `application` tag

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul for your answer! However due to some UI specifics of my app, I need to reduce the set of devices. For example I'm not going to support tablets, or devices with low resolutions. `<support-screens ...>` doesn't help me. I mean Pixel 3 and Pixel 3a become compatible. The side effect of such solution - many other undesirable devices become compatible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value `440` available, while you could still define a minimum screen width in DPI with `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp`, with a value larger than the screens to filter out.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: When I set, for example, `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"` tablets become compatible. Adding `android:xlargeScreens="false"` doesn't help. https://imgur.com/g4mzFjw

Comment: Of course you shouldn't set the smallest value possible... that's not what I've written.