# In defining the compatibilities in Android Manifest, which way is correct?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

While adding the compatibility versions of screens in manifest, I have this doubt, which way is the correct way as per Android developing.

Is this correct?

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi | mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | 280 | 360 | 420 | 480 | 560" />
```

or below is correct?

```
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="280" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the below solution worked. Please try with this solution

```
 <compatible-screens>

        <!--all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />

        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />

    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I added my code in Manifest.xml with out these "280 | 360 | 420 | 480 | 560" and released my app, its not compatible with the mobiles which has the "420 Dpi". Specifically Samsung SM-A750FN + Nokia 7 plus both are 420 dpi mobiles, it is not added in supported devices on my google developer account

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852700/devices-with-screen-density-440-dpi-are-not-compatible-with-app-being-published please refer to this link and check if it works